# How to split a date range in a row into time spent in each hour in a day in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like below with a start and end date. The record would start and finish on the same day only.

I want to expand each record to have hour columns which would contains time spent in each hour. For example:

```
ID      START_TIME        END_TIME           
AAAA    09/10/2015 9:30   09/10/2015 13:15
```

would become

```
ID      START_TIME      END_TIME        H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9  H10 H11 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16 H17 H18 H19 H20 H21 H22 H23 H24

AAAA    9/10/2015 9:30  9/10/2015 13:15 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   30  60  60  60  15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?   Please post the query you are using, and what results you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by creating a table that has 24 rows for the hours, with hour number and start & end time, cross join that with the data, use the extra table for calculation and use pivot to get the data back together.

This has a little ugly hack for handling the end of the day, and deducts one second from the end times for that.

SQL:

```
with data as (
  select *,
  case when convert(time, endtime) < S or convert(time, starttime) > E
  then 0 else 
    60
    - case when S < convert(time, starttime) and E > convert(time, starttime)
      then datediff(minute, convert(time, starttime), E) else 0 end
    - case when S < convert(time, endtime) and E >= convert(time, endtime)
      then datediff(second, dateadd(second, -1, convert(time, endtime)), E) / 60 else 0 end
  end as minutes
  from table1 d cross join hours h
)

select * from 
(SELECT id, starttime, endtime, h, minutes from data) p
PIVOT
(
sum (minutes)
FOR H IN
([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23])
) AS pvt
```

The setup I used:

```
create table table1 (
  id char(4),
  starttime datetime,
  endtime datetime
)

insert into table1 values 
('AAAA','09/10/2015 9:30','09/10/2015 13:15'),
('BBBB','09/10/2015 9:30','09/10/2015 23:59')

create table hours (
  H tinyint,
  S time,
  E time
)

insert into hours values 
(0,'00:00','01:00'),
(1,'01:00','02:00'),
(2,'02:00','03:00'),
(3,'03:00','04:00'),
(4,'04:00','05:00'),
(5,'05:00','06:00'),
(6,'06:00','07:00'),
(7,'07:00','08:00'),
(8,'08:00','09:00'),
(9,'09:00','10:00'),
(10,'10:00','11:00'),
(11,'11:00','12:00'),
(12,'12:00','13:00'),
(13,'13:00','14:00'),
(14,'14:00','15:00'),
(15,'15:00','16:00'),
(16,'16:00','17:00'),
(17,'17:00','18:00'),
(18,'18:00','19:00'),
(19,'19:00','20:00'),
(20,'20:00','21:00'),
(21,'21:00','22:00'),
(22,'22:00','23:00'),
(23,'23:00','23:59:59')
```

The same example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61f98/3)

Comment: I read you mention a `hack` for end of the day, but OP say date will always be same date. Anyway great solution.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That's for times ending after 23:00, because the end time in the helper table is 23:59:59, which means one minute less than it should be, and that's why -1 second

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a massive `case` statement.  The logic for the number of minutes in each hour is based on whether the time span begins before, during, or after the hour, and whether it ends before, during, or after:

```
select id, start_time, end_time,
       ((case when datepart(hour, end_time) < 0 then 0
              when datepart(hour, end_time) = 0 then datepart(minute, end_time)
              else 60
         end)
        (case when datepart(hour, start_time) < 0 then 60
              when datepart(hour, start_time) = 0 then datepart(minute, start_time)
              else 0
         end)
       ) as h00,
       ((case when datepart(hour, end_time) < 1 then 0
              when datepart(hour, end_time) = 1 then datepart(minute, end_time)
              else 60
         end)
        (case when datepart(hour, start_time) < 1 then 60
              when datepart(hour, start_time) = 1 then datepart(minute, start_time)
              else 0
         end)
       ) as h01,
       . . .
```

Comment: Are you missing some kind of operator between the two case statements in each column?

Comment: Agree with @TabAlleman, what happen between those `CASE`  for each hour? I tought on a similar solution but tought you will have some fancy function under your belt